# CSS buttons wont center in my navigation

Tags: html, css, button, navigation, center

Trying to have my buttons centered above the text below. I think it has to do with my float lefts, but i believe i need to still float it left because the content afterwards is also floating.

Margin: 0 auto; isnt working.

Please Advise:

```
.button {
    background-color:  rgb(214,52,49);
    padding: 4px 24px;
    border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    display: block;
    width: 150px; /* 150 / 980 */
}

nav { 
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: green;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}

nav a.button {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


nav a.button:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 150px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/117sparten/kNZEs/3/

Comment: do u want that you button center in green background

Comment: yup, thats the goal =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/kNZEs/9/).

```
<header>
   <nav>
      <div class="btngroup">
         <a href="#" class="button">contact</a>
         <a href="#" class="button">blog</a>
      </div>
   </nav>
</header>

.button {
    background-color:  rgb(214,52,49);
    padding: 4px 24px;
    border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px; /* 150 / 980 */
}

.button:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

nav { 
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: green;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}

nav div.btngroup {
    width: 410px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 
}

nav a.button {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change `nav a.button` like this:

`nav a.button {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}`

or

`nav a.button {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
}`

Answer (score 1):

use this inline-block property in button class

```
.button
{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

and remove float property from nav a.button

Comment: i have removed the unneeded float thank you for pointing that out